# Global and Local feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier

For an Electronic HNC assignment I have been asked to design an op-amp based multistage amplifier with a gain of 40dB for a 100kHz signal. I am supposed to being looking at the effects of local and global feedback, however I am unable to find any information on these two types of feedback.

Comment: you need an opamp with a gain_bandwidth product of at least10MHz. It's as simple as that plus a couple of resistors and capacitors. Single local feedback and that's it. Now please justify why it needs multiple levels of feedback.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a show and tell site.

Comment: @user33497  You should sharpen your question.  What are you trying to do?  What have you done?  What are you trying to find out?  Welcome to EE.SE, by the way.  If you're trying to crowdsource a class assignment, you should be very weary.

Comment: *"I am unable to find any information on these two types of feedback."*  Then, it can only be the case that you haven't made a significant effort to look since the terms are well known and widely used in the literature.  Voting to close for lack of effort.

Answer (score 2):

**Local feedback:** Feed the opamp's output back to that opamp's own input.

**Global feedback:** Feed the (multistage) amplifier's output back into the (multistage) amplifier's input.

The question is about how the amplifier properties (like bandwidth, maybe other properties that I can't think of right now) change with changing the feedback architecture. Notice that you can use either on its own or both at the same time.